# Calculate the Hamming Distance between the two same datasets

Tags: math, dataset, measure, hamming-distance

How to Calculate the Hamming Distance between two datasets of same points?Both the data sets look exactly the same.
http://postimg.org/image/u11qnsolh/

There are two datasets of same number of points.
total number of points -19

---

First data set has 3 clusters.
Cluster A has 4 points in it
Cluster B has 2 points in it
Cluster C has 4 points in it

Rest of the points are outside the cluster

---

Second data set has 3 clusters.
Cluster A has 8 points in it
Cluster B has 5 points in it
Cluster C has 6 points in it

Answer (score 1):

First, let's index the points:

[image]

You are interested in the Hamming distance between two sets of sets:

*L = { {1,2,3,4}, {5,6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14,15,17,18}, {16}, {19} }*

*R = { {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12,13}, {14,15,16,17,18,19} }*

---

Adapting from [[ 1 ]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.224.4799) (section 2), generalizing Hamming distance to two sets X,Y, the distance can be defined as:

[image]

Adapting from [[ 2 ]](http://udoo.uni-muenster.de/downloads/publications/2330.pdf) (section 3.4), the union  and the difference between two sets of sets can be defined as:

[image]

and

[image]

so in your case:

*L ⋃ R = { {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12,13}, {14,15,16,17,18,19} }*

*L - R = { {} }*

*R - L = { {5,6,7,8}, {1,2,3,4,7,8}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,8}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, {10,11,12,13}, {9,11,12,13}, {9,10,12,13}, {9,10,11,13}, {9,10,11,12}, {16,19}, {14,15,17,18,19}, {14,15,16,17,18} }*

*(L-R) ⋃ (R-L) = { {}, {5,6,7,8}, {1,2,3,4,7,8}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,8}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, {10,11,12,13}, {9,11,12,13}, {9,10,12,13}, {9,10,11,13}, {9,10,11,12}, {16,19}, {14,15,17,18,19}, {14,15,16,17,18} }*

so

*|(L-R) ⋃ (R-L)| = 13*

and

*|L ⋃ R| = 3*

so d(L,R) = 13 / 3 = 4.333

---

[ 1 ] *Generalizing Hamming Distance to Finite Sets to the purpose of classifying heterogeneous objects [Bezem, Keijzer, Volmac]*

[ 2 ] *Pattern Matching in Conceptual Models – A Formal Multi-Modelling Language Approach [Delfmann, Herwig, Lis, Stein]*